# How to Clean Start System with Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm, versioning

It appears that my computer, which I am learning Bootstrap/Angular development on, has a terrible versioning problem? Everytime I download a repo from the web the projects through version errors on my system. Even projects I pull from various books do the same thing.

I've looked all over but can't seem to find a technique for removing all the library files and reloading all the correct, current working files. Anyone with a solution to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific about what errors are you getting, what projects are you trying to run and how are you trying to run them (how are you installing the npm packages?).

Comment: I am doing the following when I download an app from another source (book or Github):
npm install
npm run start
Depending on the source I get all kinds of errors and failure to run. 
What I am really asking is how can you clear off your system of all the apps it takes to work with these apps? Node, Ruby, Bootstrap, Typescript, etc. There is no "uninstall all" so that I can refresh the whole install. 
This all started after I updated Typescript.